# PRO*C compile wrong comments

Tags: c, oracle11g, comments, oracle-pro-c

I've a strange behaviour on my pc when a I precompile a .pc source file. I use a command line instruction, like "proc wpd_ric_pla_02.pc wpd_ric_pla_02.c CODE=ANSI_C".
If I compile the very same source file on another machine, with the exact same version of proc (11.1.0.7.0), instead, I have no issue.
I attach an image showing some differences in the .c generated.[image]
You can see on the left the correct .c and, on the right, the .c generated on my machine. SQL instructions are wrongly commented out.
Could someone please help me understand why this happens?
Thank you, Sebastian.

Comment: NB: I have no issues with other .pc source files

Answer (score 0):

It may have something to do with the file being copied from one machine to the other. But this is only a wild guess.

Maybe the wrong file have some non-visible characters that are messing the compiler.

You can check it by doing a `hexdump -c wpd_ric_pla_02.pc` if you are in Linux.
If you are using Windows I suggest you use Notepad++ `View / Show Symbol / Show All Characters` function.

If that doesn't work, try isolting the problem in a single query.

Comment: Thanks. I already tried to inspect it with Notepad++, to copy the file back to my machine from the one it works, and also to rewrite manually some pieces of SQL, deleting all lines before writing them back. The source file is very long though, and I'll try and inspect it byte by byte.

Comment: Hello again. I checked the source file via java FileInputStream. If read() returns every single byte of it, it contains nothing strange. Just line feeds, carriage returns (and every LF has its own CR), tabs, blank spaces, standard ASCII characters (range 33 to 125) and a bunch of accented letters (à, è, etc.).

Comment: Since you have a huge file, the next step is that you try and isolate the problem. You should make a backup and then start removing the parts that work until you have only the part that don't in the file. With that in hand you can analyze locally and try to rewrite it, maybe